# Keep values after page reload of javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I know this is a topic where you can find tons of answers for... I spent now quite some time to search for the solution I am looking for.

I have a PHP file with a form. This PHP file uses a JavaScript for a drop down pre-selection.
Means: If a user selects a value in drop-down1 then there is a limited selection in drop-down2.
This JavaScript definitely needs to reload the PHP file for changing the values of the second drop-down2 list.

The question is now: How can I keep the entered values of the user in the form, after the JavaScript has been executed. Currently all entered data get lost.

One option would be to set all values into the URL and grab them with GET. Yes.. that would be an option but as I am using 13 values, the URL would look not too nice. I don't want to user to take notice of what happens.
I cant use the POST, as I don't push the posting button.. it's just the JavaScript that gets executed and reloads the page.

I thought about filling the Session with the entered data but that is not directly possible as JavaScript is on the client side and the session is on the server side.

Do you have any suggestions?

Form Example:
First Name (text box)   Last Name (text box)    Age (drop-down)        Sex (drop-down)

Province (JS drop down) District (JS drop down) Commune (JS drop down) Village (JS drop down)

Transf.from (drop down) Health Center (text box) Ambulance (drop-down) Self.transferred (drop down)    SEND BUTTON

dynmicoptionlist.js code:

```
   //Set parameters for provinces selection
   function reload1(form) {

      var val1=form.provinces.options[form.provinces.options.selectedIndex].value;

      //Get the current URL
      var url1=window.location.href;

      //Check if the current URL has the search term in it (-1 means it is not in it)
      if(url1.search("&provinces=") != -1) {

         //Now that the search term was found, cut the search term from the URL so that it can be replaced
         //This is necessary for multiple selections in the same drop down box
     var url2 = url1.substr(0,url1.search("&provinces="));

         //If the user has selected "Please select", then dont add the provinces parameter
         if(val1 == "") {

        //Create the new URL
            self.location= url2
         }
         else {

            //Create the new URL
            self.location= url2 + "&provinces=" + val1 ;
         }
      }
      else {

         //The search term was not found, so just add the provinces
         self.location= url1 + "&provinces=" + val1;
      }
   }

   //Set parameters for districts selection
   function reload2(form) {

      var val1=form.provinces.options[form.provinces.options.selectedIndex].value; 
      var val2=form.districts.options[form.districts.options.selectedIndex].value; 

      //Get the current URL
      var url1=window.location.href;

      //Check if the current URL has the search term in it (-1 means it is not in it)
      if(url1.search("&districts=") != -1) {

         //Now that the search term was found, cut the search term from the URL so that it can be replaced
         //This is necessary for multiple selections in the same drop down box
         var url2 = url1.substr(0,url1.search("&districts="));

         //If the user has selected "Please select", then dont add the provinces parameter
         if(val2 == "") {

        //Create the new URL
            self.location= url2
         }
         else {

            //Create the new URL
            self.location= url2 + "&districts=" + val2 ;
         }
      }
      else {

         //The search term was not found, so just add the districts
         self.location= url1 + "&districts=" + val2;
      }
   }

   //Set parameters for communes selection
   function reload3(form) {

      var val1=form.provinces.options[form.provinces.options.selectedIndex].value; 
      var val2=form.districts.options[form.districts.options.selectedIndex].value; 
      var val3=form.communes.options[form.communes.options.selectedIndex].value; 

      //Get the current URL
      var url1=window.location.href;

      //Check if the current URL has the search term in it (-1 means it is not in it)
      if(url1.search("&communes=") != -1) {

         //Now that the search term was found, cut the search term from the URL so that it can be replaced
         //This is necessary for multiple selections in the same drop down box
         var url2 = url1.substr(0,url1.search("&communes="));

             //If the user has selected "Please select", then dont add the provinces parameter
         if(val3 == "") {

        //Create the new URL
            self.location= url2
         }
         else {

            //Create the new URL
            self.location= url2 + "&communes=" + val3 ;
         }
      }
      else {

         //The search term was not found, so just add the communes
         self.location= url1 + "&communes=" + val3;
      }
   }
```

---

On behalf of JohnP's suggestion here are my changes so far:
I've added the onload function to fill the hidden field with a value:

```
<body onload=\"setValue()\">
```

The JavaScript filling the value looks like this:

```
<script type=\"text/javascript\">

   function setValue() {

      document.getElementById(\"dyndrpdwnhidden\").value=\"createPatient\";
   }
</script>
```

In my form I've added the hidden field:

```
<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"dyndrpdwnhidden\">
```

To get the values out of the form's input fields in my JavaScript dynmicoptionlist.js above I've used as an example:

```
var entry_date = form.entry_date.value;
```

Comment: If you know JQuery couldnt you use an ajax call to call the php script without refreshing the form page? Or just normal ajax call, just JQuery makes it very simple to use ajax calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just make your JS submit the form? That will make the variables available, and you can activate the second dropdown by looking at the post data instead of the $_GET data that the JS sends.

Comment: exactly, you can submit forms with JS with myFormObject.submit()

Comment: If I submit the form, the following action will result in writing a dataset into the database. As the Drop-Down is just in the middle of the form I think the text boxes/other drop down lists might not have been entered by the user yet.
I have added a sample of the form in my original post.

Comment: You can simply set a value in a hidden field indicating that the form is not being submitted to save, but merely to grab the drop down data.

Comment: Sorry for asking but does this mean like I submit the form with JS (just for building up the following drop down lists) but the final submit of the form can still be executed the way it is right now (html)?

Comment: @Daniel, yup. Usually you handle this by setting the value of a hidden field to a default value on page load (e.g. - `save`), but when the dropdown value changes JS can change that value to something else and submit the form. In your PHP code, you simply save the form only if the value in the hidden field is the default value. It sounds complicated, but it's not. You can also make it work without JS as well so you don't break accessibility

Comment: @JohnP: Alright...think I got most of it. But I don't get why I should save the form only if the value in the hidden field is the default value. Isn't it just the other way around? If the value of the hidden field is NOT the default value, then save the form (as I want to save the changed drop down values).

Comment: @Daniel the order doesn't matter. You only need a state indicator to figure out who's doing what

Comment: @Daniel why not post a new question with all the things you learned here? Make sure you add all the appropriate details. I could offer you some guidance when I get home

Comment: @JohnP: I am sorry again.. tried it on my own but didn't succeed.
Please find my changes in my original post.
So depending on the default value of the hidden field, I can now differentiate between different submits.
I can even read the values out of the fields and put them into JS variables. But for me it is still not clear how to get the values back to the input fields with a JS submit.

Beside that: As I hate JS, could you please provide a dummy safe example on how to do it without JS so that I dont break accessibility? That would be the perfect solution for me. Again: Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Daniel are you still having issues with this?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you try to use SESSION? The session data will not disappear even on page refresh or redirect.

To keep any data:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['data']=$_POST['data_from_previous_page'];
```

To read it at any page:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['data'];
```

To clear all session data:

```
unset($_SESSION);
if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
   setcookie(session_name(), '', time()-42000, '/');
}
session_destroy();
```

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong but for my understanding I can use POST only if I send the form. As this is not happening (the JavaScript just reloads the page) I can't use it, right?

Comment: @Daniel, that is correct, SESSION is only applicable if you POST the form. I understand your issue now but at the moment, I am still thinking of a simple solution for you. But actually the problem can be resolved if you can stop the java to reload the page upon changes in the select box. Jquery Ajax can make it very easy to do that. So if the page doesn't get reloaded upon changes to the select box, you are good to go. But that would mean you have to change coding and add Jquery which I think you are not interested yet. Let me ponder and do some research on it, I am sure there is a solution.

Comment: @Daniel : Can you share the JS drop down code you are using? Maybe I can mod it using Jquery and Ajax so the page doesn't reload but merely update the select box content upon change. Better if you can show us that page you are developing, your page design is pretty vague to me. If I know more then a work around is easier to be found.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort mmk! I've added the sourcecode of my JS drop down.

Comment: @Daniel : Would it possible for you to post the link to you web apps if it is opened to the public, so I can have a better assessment before I write up a mod code.

Comment: @mmk: I am very sorry but it is an App for our Intranet.. so not open to the public... but I could send you the files if that is fine with you?!

Answer (score 0):

use localStorage https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_storage.asp

Storage Object
The Storage object of the Web Storage API provides access to the session storage or local storage for a particular domain. This allows you to read, add, modify, and delete stored data items.